# Que me falla en este codigo de calculadora introducida por el usuario?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora en **C#** que devuelva el resultado introducido por el usuario.

Por lo tanto tiene que leer tanto los dígitos como el signo operador introducido por teclado, hasta ahora he llegado hasta aquí pero no se como seguir.

Así que a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. La cuestión es que se que voy bien encaminado pero no se las cosas que fallan, así que si alguien es tan amable...

**Código:**

```
string operacion;
        int longitud;
        string simbolo; 
        int primerNum;
        int segundoNum;
        string operador;

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce una operacion.");
        operacion = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        longitud = operacion.Length;
        //operacion.Substring(0, longitud);


        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            string digito = operacion.Substring(i, 1);






            if (Char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(digito)))
            {


            }
            else
            {

                primerNum = Convert.ToInt32(operacion.Substring(0, operacion.IndexOf(digito)));
                segundoNum = Convert.ToInt32(operacion.Substring(operacion.IndexOf(digito)));
                operador = Convert.ToString(digito);
                if (operador == "x")
                {
                    int multi = primerNum * segundoNum;
                }
                else if(operador == "-")
                {

                }
                else if (operador == "+")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una suma");

                }
                else if(operador == "/")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una division");

                }
            }

        }
```

Muchas gracias :)

Edito:

Modificación del código realizada en base a sugerencias recibidas por parte de @OtroBrayan.

Creo que el planteamiento del método está bien pero no sé por qué, a la hora de introducir la operación el programa crashea y me devuelve el error System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. 
Entiendo que el crash se produce a la hora de interpretar el operador, puesto que sí introduzco simplemente carácteres en forma de número los interpreta correctamente.

**Código**

```
string operacion;
        int longitud;
        string primerNumSTR;
        int primerNum;
        string segundoNumSTR;
        int segundoNum;
        string operador;

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce una operacion.");
        operacion = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        longitud = operacion.Length;
        //operacion.Substring(0, longitud);


        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            string digito = operacion.Substring(i, 1);






            if (Char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(digito)))
            {


            }
            else
            {

                 operador = Convert.ToString(digito);
                 primerNumSTR = (operacion.Substring(0, Convert.ToInt32(operador)));
                 primerNum = Convert.ToInt32(primerNumSTR);
                 segundoNumSTR = (operacion.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(operador), operacion.Length));
                 segundoNum = Convert.ToInt32(segundoNumSTR);
                if (operador == "x")
                {
                    int multi = primerNum * segundoNum;
                }
                else if(operador == "-")
                {

                }
                else if (operador == "+")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una suma");

                }
                else if(operador == "/")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una division");

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: no entiendo, porque iteras por el Length de la operacion? acaso se ingresa una formular como ser: `20+5` y esperas obtener la repsuesta, porque si es asi al iterar por cada posicion como sabria que se ingreso en este caso un 20, porque al iterar cada posicion tomarias un 2 y un 0 por separado

Comment: Mi intención es la de que el bucle recorra cada carácter de la cadena para reconocer el operador,  tras esto en la siguiente vuelta almacenar en una variable los digitos anteriores al operador y los siguientes. Y en la siguiente vuelta del bucle,  operar los resultados de las 2 variables mediante el operador reconocido anteriormente. La cuestión esque apenas llevó 4 días programando en C#(estoy en un bootcamp)  por lo que aún no tengo claros algunos conceptos. Sobre el papel creo que mi idea funcionaria pero no se el procedimiento exacto para ejecutarla. (Lo siento, dudas de newbie :) )

Answer (score 0):

Con un `"Contains"` podrías ahorrarte lo de la comparación, y considerando que guardas cada numero en una variable no tendrías necesidad tampoco de usar el ciclo for.
Podrías hacer algo como:

```
int num1
INT num2
string operador
string resul
//pides los datos a ingresar
if(Operador.Contains("+"){
res=num1+num2;
Console.WriteLine("Tu operación es una suma y el resultado es: "+ res);

}else  if(Operador.Contains("*"){
    res=num1*num2;
    Console.WriteLine("Tu operación es una multiplicación y el resultado es: "+ res);
```

y así sucesivamente... pienso que eso ha de solventar y de esa forma no te das "mala vida"

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que quieres decir,  pero como me ahorro el bucle for?  Es decir,  como recorro la cadena hasta y/o desde el operador y almacenó los resultados en una variable sin necesidad de usar el for? Es decir,  veo el recorrido del ciclo necesario primero para extraer el operador y segundo para almacenar en ambas variables todo lo anterior y todo lo siguiente al operador.  Se puede hacer esto sin usar el for?

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como:

```
   namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string operacion;
            int primerNum;
            int segundoNum;
            int resp = 0;


            Console.WriteLine("Introduce una operacion.");
            operacion = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (operacion.Contains("+"))
            {
                String[] NumS = operacion.Split('+');

                //   Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una suma");
                primerNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumS[0]);
                segundoNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumS[1]);
                resp = primerNum + segundoNum;
                Console.WriteLine(resp);
            }

            else if (operacion.Contains("*"))
            {
                String[] NumM = operacion.Split('*');

                //   Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una Multiplicacion");
                primerNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumM[0]);
                segundoNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumM[1]);
                resp = primerNum * segundoNum;
                Console.WriteLine(resp);

            }
            else if (operacion.Contains("/"))
            {
                String[] NumM = operacion.Split('/');

                //   Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una Division");
                primerNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumM[0]);
                segundoNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumM[1]);
                resp = primerNum / segundoNum;
                Console.WriteLine(resp);

            }
            else if (operacion.Contains("-"))
            {
                String[] NumM = operacion.Split('-');

                //   Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una Resta");
                primerNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumM[0]);
                segundoNum = Convert.ToInt32(NumM[1]);
                resp = primerNum - segundoNum;
                Console.WriteLine(resp);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

espero resuelva tu problema

Comment: Visto de esa forma está perfecto. La cuestión es que hasta el Lunes no me toca ver las arrays (aunque más o menos sé cómo funcionan) y tampoco había visto hasta ahora la función .Split, por lo que no podría haber desarrollado este método. En cualquier caso muchas gracias, duda resuelta y algo nuevo aprendido :)

Comment: La investigación es algo del día a día y eso ningun profesor puede discutirtelo, pero para resolver tu inquietud sin usar un Split y tampoco Array podrias usar un Switch Case, si lo anterior tampoco lo has visto aun podrias enviar a leer 3 veces por consola donde pidas 

// Ingrese No1
// Ingrese Operador
// Ingrese No2

seria breve, poco optimo pero breve

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta de cara a proximos proyectos más complejos. El Switch si lo he visto y lo controlo. La cosa es que mi compañera de proyecto iba a hacerlo utilizando precisamente ese método(Switch), por lo que mi intención era crear otro totalmente diferente. De todas maneras estoy intentando desarrollar un método en base a tu anterior comentario. Si te parece bien edito y le echas un vistazo a ver qué me puedes comentar sobre ello.